# How can I convert a file descriptor (int fd) to a file pointer ( FILE* fp )

Tags: c++, file, mfc

I can use CFile to get member m_hFile,how to get the CFile's file descriptor(like File*)?I need to convert file handle to file pointer.
  Thanks!

Comment: The dup wasn't mfc specific, but the same principle applies. Just use [_fdopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge CFile doesn't use the FILE * abstraction (it uses the windows ReadFile/WriteFile APIs), however you can use _fdopen to get a FILE * from a file descriptor and _open_osfhandl to get a file descriptor for a HANDLE.

You can also use CStdioFile to use FILE * based file operations.